# Integral of function with a pretty long name

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, special-functions, improper-integrals

I am looking for a compact result of this integral:

$$\int_R^\infty k_n(x) \, dx,$$

where $k_n$ is the modified spherical Bessel function of the second kind ([explanation to this function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedSphericalBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html)).

Actually, [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%20sqrt%282%20%5Cpi/x%29%2aBesselK%5Bn%2b1/2,%20x%5D%20dx) has an antiderivate, but it is quite messy and I guess that the upper limit should always be zero. Can we simplify something there for $R>0$? ${{{{}}}}$

Comment: The relation (15) on Wolfram page can be used to establish a recurrence relation for these integrals

Comment: Probably, if you want to do it this way, it could be faster to use those relation given on the other page(explanation to this function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that $k_n(x)$ has a pretty [nifty integral representation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.54):

$$k_n(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} \int_1^{\infty} dt \, P_n(t) \, e^{-x t}$$

where $P_n$ is a Legendre polynomial of the first kind, so that

$$\int_R^{\infty} dx \, k_n(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} R \int_1^{\infty} dt \, P_n(t) \, \int_1^{\infty} du \, e^{-R t u}$$

(Note that I reversed the order of integration and made the substitution $x=R u$.)  We may simplify this to a single integral:

$$\int_R^{\infty} dx \, k_n(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} \int_1^{\infty} dt \, P_n(t) \frac{e^{-R t}}{t}$$

Clearly, we may use the recurrence relation for the Legendre polynomials:

$$(n+1) P_{n+1}(x) = (2 n+1) P_n(x) - n P_{n-1}(x)$$

in conjunction with the initial values of the integral at $n=0$ and $n=1$:

$$\int_R^{\infty} dx \, k_0(x) = -\frac{\pi}{2}\text{Ei}(-R)$$
$$\int_R^{\infty} dx \, k_1(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{e^{-R}}{R}$$

uniquely specifies the value of the integral for arbitrary $n$.